# Avoid Loop for Selecting Dimensions in a Batch Tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a batch tensor and another tensor having indices of the dimensions to select from  batch tensor. At present, I am looping around batch tensor as shown below in the code snippet:

```
import torch

# create tensors to represent our data in torch format
batch_size = 8
batch_data = torch.rand(batch_size, 3, 240, 320)

# notice that channels_id has 8 elements, i.e., = batch_size
channels_id = torch.tensor([2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0])
```

This is how I am selecting dimensions inside a for loop and then stacking to convert a single tensor:

```
batch_out = torch.stack([batch_i[channel_i] for batch_i, channel_i in zip(batch_data, channels_id)])
batch_out.size()  # prints torch.Size([8, 240, 320])
```

**It works fine. However, is there a better PyTorch way to achieve the same?**

Comment: vectorized functions are better handled in numpy. Is is possible in your case to do the operations in numpy and then convert to torch tensor. But the downside would be you can't use gpu functionalities.

Comment: look at [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html#torch.gather)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the hint from [@Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/), I could make it work using the [torch.gather](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) function. Below is the complete code:

```
import torch

# create tensors to represent our data in torch format
batch_size = 8
batch_data = torch.rand(batch_size, 3, 240, 320)

# notice that channels_id has 8 elements, i.e., batch_size
channels_id = torch.tensor([2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0])

# resizing channels_id to (8 , 1, 240, 320)
channels_id = channels_id.view(-1, 1, 1, 1).repeat((1, 1) + batch_data.size()[-2:])

batch_out = torch.gather(batch_data, 1, channels_id).squeeze()
batch_out.size()  # prints torch.Size([8, 240, 320])
```